# How does Alexa discover devices (Eco Plugs)?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, smart-plugs

I recently acquired an Eco Plug. Which is basically a Wi-Fi controlled power socket. I managed to connect to it via the EcoPlugs Android App and I can control it by turning the power on/off.

I then try to connect it to Alexa. I followed the instruction by entering my Alexa account in the app (I used my e-mail address), and then I added the EcoPlugs Skill in Alexa, verifying by entering my e-mail again. But then things went down hill from there. I am supposed to make Alexa discover the device (Eco Plug). However, I immediately get an error of `There was an error discovering your devices`. I got the same result when using Alexa App on my phone as well as Alexa through the web.

I am wondering. How does Alexa "discover" my device? I can control the plugs via cellular network which means it is managed through the cloud. Shouldn't Alexa already got the list of devices? What was it trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to try and see if this works, but on the [Smarthings blog](https://blog.smartthings.com/featured/alexa-turn-on-my-smartthings/), there is another user who was having the same problem.  He wrote,

> Can't this to work, I linked my account but Alexa can't discover devices, I get an error "There was an error discovering your devices". If I ask Alexa to discover she replies back that will search and that it takes up to 20 seconds then responds that command is not supported.

The solution for him was simply to unplug the Echo for 30 seconds and plug it back in.  He then searched for devices again, and it worked.

Hope this helps!